# Get all node name from .dae in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, nodes, collada

I'm importing a collada file in my scene. I want to know how I could list all the nodes name ?

I did this, which gives me only one name:

```
var dae;
loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
loader.load( './models/collada/test.dae', function ( collada ) {
    var dae = collada.scene;
    dae.traverse( function ( child ){
        objects.push(child);
    } );

    daenode = dae.children[0].name;
    console.log(daenode);
```

Comment: is `objects` an array? You are not looping through it?

Comment: Yes `objects` is an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your code I assume `objects` is an array. So why not use

```
for( var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++ ) {
    console.log(objects[i].name);
}
```

Comment: Yes it works! But it doesn't give me the nodes only. I have lines with nothing which parents are nodes. Do you know why?

Comment: yes because the .dae has a lot of nodes in it which might not have names. You should focus only on the nodes you need.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation. :)
In fact, I want to create some kind of hierarchy, to show what composes the dae